# Vertical alignment of table content in a view

Tags: views, 8

I have a table view with two columns, one of which contains an image which is quite high.

The text in the second column is relatively brief but is displaying in the vertical centre of its cell (where I would like to align it to the top of the cell).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to set `td {vertical-align: top;}` in your theme css for the cell with text in it.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping this would be possible without modifying my theme's CSS. I'll do this if there really is no alternative but seems a bit weird that horizontal alignment can be modified in the UI, but not vertical alignment?

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing something similar and put this code in each of the cells where I wanted the information top aligned . . .

```
<td style="vertical-align:top">
```

It has worked well for me. Overrides the CSS as I only needed it in select cells.